# How to pass SoapObject from one Activity to another in an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, serializable

I need to pass a [`SoapObject`](http://kobjects.org/ksoap2/doc/api/org/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject.html) from one `Activity` to another, in an `intent`. Is that possible?

I can't see it implementing `Serializable`, but it does implement `KvmSerializable` (although I don't know whatever it is).

Comment: Are you tried with GSon to parse it in String and pass that String to Another Activity and then again cast to SoapObject while Fetching. As I am also not used that butif you want to try then i supplied the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing it via an intent seems overkill. Just have it stored in a singleton or a static class that is accessible from both activities.

Answer (score 2):

Passing control between `Activity` instances is treated like inter-process communication.  The `Intent` contains the control and data parameters of this "calling convention".

Because of this, there are limits on what you can pass.  An `Intent` can only pass along objects that can be stored in a `Bundle`.  This includes the "value" types, some types of `ArrayList`, `Parcelable`, and `Serializable`.  An arbitrary object cannot be passed.  See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) for details.

The ksoap2 `KvmSerializable` is not derived from `Serializable`.  You must serialize and deserialize it yourself.

You could make a subclass of `SoapObject` and you can add `Serializable` to it directly.  However, you must use the ksoap2 API to participate in [Java Serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) meaning you must implement some code to account for "internals" of your `SoapObject`.

Another alternative is to make a `SoapObject` subclass implement the `Parcelable` interface.  The code to implement is similar to custom Java Serialization.

You could pass the original XML if that is available, then re-parse it in the receiving `Activity`.

As a last resort, @RajanBhavsar above recommended a JSON string, that is a reasonable plan.  Since the ksoap2 API seems to use an "indirect" property model, I'm not sure how that would happen automatically.